# Can't get SharedPreferences to save on a handful of phones

Tags: android

I've got a phone (Samsung GT-I9000) running android 2.2.1. Saving to shared preferences fails:

```
Editor editor = ...;
if (!editor.commit()) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Nope!");
}
```

I can see it spits out the related following log statement:

```
12-10 14:06:03.919: E/ApplicationContext(4684): 
    Couldn't rename file
    /dbdata/databases/com.me.myapp/shared_prefs/com.me.prefs.xml to backup file
    /dbdata/databases/com.me.myapp/shared_prefs/com.me.prefs.xml.bak
12-10 14:06:03.919: E/MyApp(200): Nope!
```

Any idea how I can fix this? This is extremely frustrating.

Thanks

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: see this issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359

Comment: The rest of the code is omitted, it's pretty standard, works on hundreds of thousands of other devices. It looks like the issue linked to by the second commenter is the problem. Thank you. Can you add that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using a samsung galaxy S device from 2.2 to 2.2.1 .then  we  look at the path as in log its trying to save to... `"/dbdata/databases/xx.xx.xx/shared_prefs/com.me.prefs.xml"` rather than `"/data/databases/com.me.myapp/shared_prefs/com.me.prefs.xml"`. It is a problem on Samsung devices.

you can following issue posted by  dustin in Android current open issues list :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359